# Форма личного местоимения, замещающего счётный оборот с процентами

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, согласование, числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание

*Примерно **80% информации**, которая даётся на лекциях, можно спокойно выбросить, поскольку **их/её** нельзя применить для решении практических задач.*

В Интернете можно найти статьи про согласование сказуемого со счётными оборотами, содержащими проценты, но вот сведений про выбор формы личного местоимения при замещении таких счётных оборотов нигде нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно 80% ***информации***, ***которая*** даётся на лекциях, можно спокойно выбросить, поскольку ***её*** нельзя применить для решении практических задач.

**Общий смысл предложения понятен,** а непонятно получается в том случае, если предложение **начинают делить на части и оценивать их семантическую правильность.**

И вот в этом случае надо вспомнить **общие правила,** которые выглядят примерно так.

1) В теме количественных сочетаний  действуют **два принципа, смысловой и формальный**.  Сочетаемость рядом расположенных слов (формальный принцип) не менее важен, чем семантический.

2) Так, **счетный оборот рассматривается как единый член предложения**, при этом грамматически ему приписывается или мн. число, или ед. число, средний род. (Неважно, что по смыслу речь идет о множестве предметов).

3) Оборот может иметь **определение, но оно ставится во мн. числе** (эти семь домов). И т.д.

**Еще одно правило для местоимений:**

Местоимение 3-го лица (он, она, оно, они) обычно заменяет **ближайшее к нему предшествующее существительное** в форме того же рода и числа. (Однако эта связь местоимения с существительным определяется иногда смыслом, а не формально порядком слов).

**Вот и применяем эти правила на практике.**

1) местоимение ***которая*** стоит после сущ. ***информация*** и согласуется с ним.

2) Второе местоимение ***её*** по формальному признаку **должно соответствовать** сущ. ***информация*** и местоимению ***которая*** ***(информация, она, ее***). Это общий принцип решения подобных задач.

Но если разбирать частные семантические тонкости, то от этого **пострадает общая семантика и грамматика.**

**Обозначение  смысловых оттенков, которые и так  ясны, будут затемнять смысл и усложнять грамматический строй предложения.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Вопросы, подобные заданному, заставляют задуматься над тем, как мы вообще строим и воспринимаем нашу речь. **А если сравнить этот процесс с восприятием зрительной информации.** Вот цитата на эту тему: https://lpgenerator.ru/blog/2015/12/18/5-psihologicheskih-issledovanij-po-vospriyatiyu-vizualnoj-informacii/

Вы когда-нибудь задумывались о том, как мы видим предметы? Как выхватываем их из всего визуального многообразия окружающей среды с помощью сенсорных стимулов? И как мы интерпретируем то, что видим?

1. **Почти 90% информации, поступающей через глаза, до мозга не доходит.** Таким образом, мозг использует **предыдущий опыт** или имеющиеся знания для конструирования реальности. 2. Визуальная информация, которую мы воспринимаем, соединяется с ранее сохраненными сведениями о мире, полученными нами опытным путем.

**Возможно, такой же процесс происходит при речевом общении.** Мы строим стандартные (знакомые для мозга)  фразы, в которых нужная информация обозначена **опорными (значащими) элементами.** В нашем случае такими опорными элементами является ряд: **информация, она, которая, ее,** то есть основное существительное и связанные с ним местоимения.

**Этот ряд и важен для понимания смысла,** он быстро обрабатывается и с легкостью воспринимается. Отклонение от него будет расцениваться как нечто неожиданное, требующее дополнительного распознавания, то есть усложняет понимание информации в целом.

**Отсюда и следует теория здравого смысла и основанные на ней правила,** согласно которым особое внимание требуется только для устранения двусмысленности речевой ситуации. В других случаях наше "роботомышление" и ненужное (искусственное) внимание к деталям приносит не пользу, а вред.

Comment: Вы пишите: _Второе местоимение "её" по формальному признаку должно соответствовать сущ. "информация" и местоимению "которая"…_ Получается мы как раз таки используем смысловой подход: "которая" относится к слову "информация", местоимение "её" относится к сочетанию "80% информации", хотя при формальном принципе оно также относится к слову "информация". И ставим мы местоимение "её", а не "их", дабы не нарушать ряд местоимений в женском роде, а задуманная нами истинная соотнесённость местоимений и так очевидна для читающего. Вы это же имеете в виду?

Comment: Да, я это имею в виду. Мы обозначаем ряд слов, связанный с одним существительным и придаем ему одну форму для ясности смысла.

Answer (score 5):

Согласна с **Sharon**, что оба варианта местоимения можно использовать, смотря что оно замещает.

1 (смысловое замещение).Примерно 80% информации, которая даётся на лекциях, можно спокойно выбросить, поскольку её (**данную информацию**, входящую в 80%) нельзя применить для решения практических задач.

2 (грамматическое). Примерно 80% информации, которая даётся на лекциях, можно спокойно выбросить, поскольку их (эти  80 % информации) нельзя применить для решения практических задач.

Счётный оборот - слитное сочетание, в нём, как в любом сочетании, есть главное слово, которое согласуется с остальными единицами. У нас это 80 процентов, в ед.числе был бы 1 процент, а 80 - уже много,значит, **они - их** -**к ним** (к 80% процентам добавить остальные 20)- **о них** (о 80 процентах).

А вообще, прав М_Г, если говорить о качестве хорошей речи, оба варианта не совсем корректны, лучше бы 
переформулировать, составить фразу без местоимения, например:

*Примерно 80% информации, которая даётся на лекциях, можно спокойно выбросить, поскольку эти сведения (этот материал, эти данные) нельзя применить для решения практических задач.*

Comment: Использовать "её", наверное, не стоит, потому что тогда формально местоимение указывает на всю информацию, которая даётся на лекциях.

Comment: Кто как понимает, слова "всю" здесь нет, можно иметь в виду и ту информацию, которая содержится в 80%. Если подходить формально, то лучше "их", если неформально, в бытовом общении, можно и "её".

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, не существует запрета на обсуждение процентов информации или самой информации. Но в данном конкретном случае нужно выбрать местоимение **её**, в противном случае предложение выглядит стилистически плохо (из-за местоимения "которая"; тогда получается, что мы говорим одновременно и об информации и о процентах).

Пример из "Иностранной литературы", 1978 г.:

> 80 процентов информации добывается обработкой открытых источников...

Вот вариант предложения, в котором будет местоимение **их**:
Остальные 80% информации могут быть выброшены, поскольку их нельзя применить для решения практических задач.

Такая формулировка возможна, хотя и непривычна, поскольку обычно мы говорим не о каждом проценте, а о всей части.

Пример из "Молодой гвардии", 1978 г.:

> Цель шпионажа — узнать остальные пять процентов информации, в которых кроется фирменный секрет...

Comment: "...Непривычна, поскольку обычно мы говорим не о каждом проценте, а о всей части." ==> Непривычна — это еще мягко сказано.

Comment: Но вот пример про цель шпионажа мне слух совсем не режет.

Comment: "...Из-за местоимения "которые" ==> Но там местоимение "которая", а это значит что *она* - это вся информация, которая даётся на лекциях, и всю **ее** нельзя применить?

Comment: "*которые*" — Это была оговорка, я исправил. Нельзя применить 80%. Точно так же, как добывается не вся информация, а только 80% (см. мой первый пример).

Comment: "Но вот пример про цель шпионажа мне слух совсем не режет" ==> Тогда по-Вашему нужно писать "их нельзя применить", а это слух режет.

Comment: Теперь Вы что-то путаете. Перечитайте, пожалуйста, мой ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88641/discussion-between---and-grizzly).

Answer (score 1):

Ответ дается **в качестве версии** для практического решения задачи.

Хотя у Розенталя нет примеров с процентами, здесь можно **ориентироваться на следующее правило:** [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_02](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_02)

8. Если при счетном обороте имеются слова **все, эти или другие в роли определения,** то сказуемое ставится во **множественном числе**, например: Недавно построены и эти семь домов;  На столе лежат приготовленные к отправке пять пакетов.

**Как же использовать это правило?**

Мы видим, что **определение влияет на структуру предложения в целом (ед. ч. или мн.ч.)**. Поэтому можно просто **условно подставить** определительное местоимение перед **выбранным** существительным, например:

(1) Примерно 80% (**той**) информации, **которая** даётся на лекциях, можно спокойно выбросить, поскольку её нельзя применить для решения практических задач.

(2) Примерно **(те)** 80% информации, **которые** даются на лекциях, можно спокойно выбросить, поскольку **их** нельзя применить для решения практических задач.

Comment: То же возражение упорно повторяю: "**её** нельзя применить" — это *о (той) информации, которая даётся на лекциях*, а не о ее части.

Comment: На мой взгляд, все решения плохи, если не менять предложение, но *ее* — хуже, чем *их*.

Comment: Предложения звучат нормально (особенное первое), лучше не составите. Дело в том, что в этой теме явно присутствует КОМПРОМИСС  между формой и содержанием (например, предметов много, а мы используем сказуемое в ед. числе).  И в правилах всегда учитываются множество факторов, обеспечивающих ОПТИМАЛЬНОЕ соотношение формальной сочетаемости форм и смысловой ясности текста.  А если будете обеспечивать идеальную сочетаемость формы, то получите  какого-нибудь МОНСТРА в части синтаксиса и смысла.

Comment: Правильно М_Г подметил: "которая даётся на лекциях" относится ко всей информации, а не только к 80%. Поэтому использовать "её", наверное, не стоит, потому что тогда формально местоимение указывает на всю информацию, которая даётся на лекциях.

Comment: Свое мнение на эту тему  я выскажу во втором ответе, пожалуйста, посмотрите.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то странно говорить о применении процентов, не так ли? Вот если бы было, скажем, 80 *мегабайт* информации, то можно было бы обсуждать оба варианта.

Comment: Речь идёт о применении не процентов, а процентов информации.

Comment: Ни один из вариантов мне не нравится. Думаю, у этой задачи нет хорошего решения.

Answer (score -1):

Личное местоимение для числового значения подобрать нетрудно — ***их***. Однако фразу следует решительно перестроить из-за делящего фразу на части оборота «которая даётся на ***лекциях***».

Не менять конструкцию в целом можно взяв указательное местоимение: «Примерно 80% информации, которая даётся на лекциях, можно спокойно выбросить, поскольку это нельзя применить для решении практических задач».

Comment: Как-то неуютно мне с этим "это", возможно кто-то сумеет найти объяснение, почему употреблять "это" в данном случае нехорошо.

Comment: Ставлю минус, поскольку я категорически не согласен со всеми утверждениями ответа.

Comment: Тогда уж и возьмите за труд — категорически опровергните эти все «утверждения»: первое, второе или сколько их там...

Comment: Это сделал не только я, но и другие участники в своих ответах. Простите, я не хочу спорить или скандалить, я просто воспользовался своим правом дать свою оценку  Вашему ответу (я ставлю на форуме примерно 1 минус на 50 плюсов в общей сложности — имею право). Многим не нравится, когда минусы ставят исподтишка, поэтому я это делаю открыто. Я не обязан что-то доказывать, но учтите, что я тоже рискую своей репутацией, ставя минусы. Не той репутацией, которая измеряется в очках, а настоящей. Поэтому всё честно, я считаю.

Comment: Столько слов, и ничего по делу. Учёл, что рискуете 1 на 50, имеете право.