# Форма личного местоимения, связанного со счетным оборотом

Tags: местоимения, количественно-именное-сочетание

Данный вопрос "вырос" из вопроса [Форма личного местоимения, замещающего счётный оборот с процентами](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447800/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8/447830#447830).

Начнем с примеров.

1. Я вылил этот стакан молока, потому что оно прокисло.
2. Я выбросил килограмм яблок, потому что они сгнили.

Первое предложение. Формально личное местоимение "оно" замещает молоко вообще, а фактически "вылитое молоко", но таких слов в предложении нет.

Второе предложение. Формально личное местоимение "они" замещает яблоки вообще, а фактически "выброшенные яблоки", но таких слов в предложении нет.

Тут заметно какое-то явление, не совпадающее с формальным представлением о замещении существительных местоимениями, но какое именно, есть ли у него название и описание — в этом хотелось бы разобраться.

Примечание. Ссылки на Розенталя по теме о том, какое существительное замещено местоимением — ближайшее к нему или удаленное — к делу не относятся, так как у Розенталя в любом случае **по смыслу** замещается  именно существительное, присутствующее в предложении, а в моих примерах это семантически не так.

Дополнение. Прошу также ответить, корректно ли связывать местоимение с первым словом в сочетании:

1. Я вылил этот стакан молока, потому что **он** прокис.
2. Я выбросил килограмм яблок, потому, что **он** сгнил.

Comment: Давайте я Вас процитирую: "Думаю, нет ничего здоровее здравого смысла.  Кому не понятно, поднимите руки". Почему Вы вдруг стали думать по-другому. Как именно? Догадайтесь сами. Это, как мне кажется, особый вид мышления.

Comment: @Sharon, Но если здравый смысл подкрепить ссылкой на правило, то чувствуешь себя еще лучше. Об этом мой вопрос.

Comment: Это и есть правило: смысловая ясность сообщения.  Ваши первые примеры очевидно правильные, а ваши вторые примеры также очевидно неправильные. Какое же еще нужно правило?  Правила используются там, где есть варианты, а здесь варианты отсутствуют.

Comment: Можно еще добавить пару примеров в доказательство того же. Я выбросила банку томатного сока, потому что она лопнула. Я выбросила банку томатного сока, потому что он закис.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне представляется более точным выражение "местоимение **ссылается** на существительное" а не "**замещает** его" (в последнем случае возникает подсознательное желание поискать совпадение падежей и т. п. показатели качества "замещения"). В данных примерах нет проблемы неоднозначности (на какое из существительных ссылается местоимение), есть лишь сомнение в совершенстве стиля: насколько *подробно* названа причина действия (пришествие в негодность яблок и молока) и нужно ли на самом деле знать, все яблоки сгнили или только выброшенные, и только ли в том стакане прокисло молоко. Скорее всего, уместность такого стиля или необходимость переформулировки (длиннее, но яснее) определяется контекстом. *Грамматической* же проблемы здесь, на мой взгляд, нет.

**P.S.** Вариант с местоимением, отвлечённо ссылающимся на *меру* (или тару), мне представляется неестественным: в высказывании заложено указание на причину, упрощенно сослаться на которую можно только в виде "яблоки (они) испортились" или "молоко (оно) прокисло". При ссылке же на меру требуется большее, например: "ибо ровно столько их сгнило" или "молоко *в нём* прокисло" (поскольку ссылка на "этот" стакан).

Answer (score 1):

Ситуации, которые я и вы описали в своих вопросах, по всей видимости, решаются по смысловому принципу и по тому, как естественнее всего передать на письме нужное нам явление действительности (о чём говорила **Sharon** [в ответе на мой вопрос про форму личного местоимения, замещающего счётный оборот с процентами](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447800/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/447830#447830)).

При использовании же формального принципа предложения зачастую неестественно  воспринимаются на слух, будто **стакан прокис**, **килограмм сгнил**, а **проценты нельзя применить для решения практических задач** (см. [тот же вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447800/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)).

Объясняется всё особенностями восприятия текста. Например, "стакан" в словосочетании "стакан молока" обозначает определённое **количество** молока (молоко объёмом в один стакан), находящееся в стакане, и, читая это словосочетание, мы воспринимаем именно молоко. Позже, когда мы ссылаемся на этот счётный оборот при помощи местоимения "он", мы мысленно соотносим местоимение со словом "стакан" в отдельности, а также с тем объектом, которое оно обозначает, тогда как в данном предложении слово "стакан" выражает лишь количество и не выражает самостоятельного объекта.

Что касается "килограмма" и "процентов", местоимения "он" и "они", которые ссылаются на них при формальном подходе, звучат неестественно из‑за того, что своей формой числа неверно передают количественную характеристику истинного субъекта:

"Он (ед. ч.) сгнил", тогда как сгнили яблоки (мн. ч.).

"Их (мн. ч.) нельзя применить для решения практических задач", тогда как нельзя применить информацию (ед. ч.).

Смысловой принцип выбора местоимения решает все указанные выше проблемы, а при чтении интуитивно понятно, что именно обозначают местоимения. Однако есть один момент, который вы как раз затронули в своём вопросе: личное местоимение ссылается на субъект, о котором в предшествующем тексте не упоминалось. По мне, это нарушение формального синтаксиса. Поэтому, вместо согласования по смыслу, я бы просто переформулировал предложения:

1. *Я вылил это **молоко в стакане**, потому что **оно** прокисло.*
2. *Я выбросил **килограмм яблок**, потому что **эти яблоки** сгнили.*
3. *Примерно **80% информации**, которая даётся на лекциях, можно спокойно выбросить, поскольку **эту информацию** нельзя применить для решения практических задач.*

Впрочем в первом предложении вашего примера можно оставить формальное согласование: не возникает резкого диссонанса между единственным числом местоимения "он" и количественной характеристикой истинного субъекта — молока, поэтому "он прокис" звучит приемлемо. Можно заметить, что именно такой диссонанс в других предложениях и режет слух.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный и содежательный ответ. Упомянутое нарушение формального синтаксиса, как видим, многие  участники  считают допустимым, так ли это — я не уверен. "Я вылил это молоко в стакане" режет слух. Молоко было в стакане, но вылили его из стакана — в этом проблема восприятия этой фразы.

Comment: @М_Г "В стакане" — несогласованное определение. Молоко, которое было в стакане, прокисло, и его вылили куда‑то. Что вылили из стакана — это всем очевидно и не нуждается в подчёркивании. Смысловой фокус то у нас на молоке.