# Можно ли местоимение "кто‑то" впоследствии заменять местоимением "он"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика, местоимения

Неопределённое местоимение "кто‑то" согласуется со сказуемым в мужском роде.

Можно ли тогда в последующем тексте заменять его местоимением "он": *Если кто-то настроен против вас, не вступайте с **ним** в противостояние*?

Или всё же лучше подбирать существительное — в данном случае, например, "неприятель"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не вижу ничего противозаконного в том, что местоимение *он* ссылается на местоимение *кто-то*.

Из Нацкорпуса:

> На самом деле, если **кто-то** раньше успешно выполнил определённую работу, вряд ли **он** повторит этот результат снова. [Кадры, которые нам не подходят // «Computerworld», 2004]
>
> Если **кто-то** ставил перед собой задачу нанести удар по обеим компаниям, то можно сказать, что **он** уже этого добился. [Алексей Полухин. Терминатор на фондовом рынке (2003) // «Время МН», 2003.08.02]
>
> Обе категории студентов учатся на равных, и если **кто-то** не справляется, **его** отчисляют независимо от того "платный" он или "бюджетный". [Анна Фенько. Студент всегда прав // «Коммерсантъ-Власть», 2002]

Примечание. Лучше говорить "местоимение ссылается на...", как заметил Alex_ander ([Форма личного местоимения, связанного со счетным оборотом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447832/%d0%a4%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc)):

> Мне представляется более точным выражение "местоимение ссылается на существительное" а не "замещает его" (в последнем случае возникает подсознательное желание поискать совпадение падежей и т. п. показатели качества "замещения").